# Apple LLVM Compiler 4.1: Error with clang Constant island pass failed to converge

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, clang

I have been stuck with this error for days. When I try archiving it fails, I have no problem to run it on the simulator or an iphone.

> **fatal error: error in backend: Constant Island pass failed to converge! Command
>   /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   failed with exit code 1**

Here is the complete compilation where it gets stuck

> CompileC
>   "/Users/RE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalaryTax-gkyeqmkkgahencbhhavdyzwrvywo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SalaryTax/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SalaryTax.build/Release-iphoneos/SalaryTax.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SalaryTaxViewController.o"
>   Classes/SalaryTaxViewController.m normal armv7 objective-c
>   com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>       cd "/Users/RE/Desktop/SalaryTax"
>       setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
>       setenv PATH "/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -isysroot /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk
>   -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion "-DIBOutlet=**attribute**((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=**attribute**((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))"
>   "-DIBAction=void)**attribute**((ibaction)" -miphoneos-version-min=5.0
>   -iquote "/Users/RE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalaryTax-gkyeqmkkgahencbhhavdyzwrvywo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SalaryTax/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SalaryTax.build/Release-iphoneos/SalaryTax.build/SalaryTax-generated-files.hmap"
>   "-I/Users/RE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalaryTax-gkyeqmkkgahencbhhavdyzwrvywo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SalaryTax/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SalaryTax.build/Release-iphoneos/SalaryTax.build/SalaryTax-own-target-headers.hmap"
>   "-I/Users/RE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalaryTax-gkyeqmkkgahencbhhavdyzwrvywo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SalaryTax/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SalaryTax.build/Release-iphoneos/SalaryTax.build/SalaryTax-all-target-headers.hmap"
>   -iquote "/Users/RE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalaryTax-gkyeqmkkgahencbhhavdyzwrvywo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SalaryTax/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SalaryTax.build/Release-iphoneos/SalaryTax.build/SalaryTax-project-headers.hmap"
>   "-I/Users/RE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalaryTax-gkyeqmkkgahencbhhavdyzwrvywo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SalaryTax/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/include"
>   -I/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
>   -I/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
>   -I/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
>   "-I/Users/RE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalaryTax-gkyeqmkkgahencbhhavdyzwrvywo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SalaryTax/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SalaryTax.build/Release-iphoneos/SalaryTax.build/DerivedSources/armv7"
>   "-I/Users/RE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalaryTax-gkyeqmkkgahencbhhavdyzwrvywo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SalaryTax/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SalaryTax.build/Release-iphoneos/SalaryTax.build/DerivedSources"
>   "-F/Users/RE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalaryTax-gkyeqmkkgahencbhhavdyzwrvywo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SalaryTax/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos"
>   -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -include "/Users/RE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalaryTax-gkyeqmkkgahencbhhavdyzwrvywo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SalaryTax/PrecompiledHeaders/SalaryTax_Prefix-bbmxcwkvhjetmzddaqqrcvabohqr/SalaryTax_Prefix.pch"
>   -MMD -MT dependencies -MF "/Users/RE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalaryTax-gkyeqmkkgahencbhhavdyzwrvywo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SalaryTax/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SalaryTax.build/Release-iphoneos/SalaryTax.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SalaryTaxViewController.d"
>   --serialize-diagnostics "/Users/RE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalaryTax-gkyeqmkkgahencbhhavdyzwrvywo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SalaryTax/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SalaryTax.build/Release-iphoneos/SalaryTax.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SalaryTaxViewController.dia"
>   -c "/Users/RE/Desktop/SalaryTax/Classes/SalaryTaxViewController.m" -o "/Users/RE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalaryTax-gkyeqmkkgahencbhhavdyzwrvywo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SalaryTax/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SalaryTax.build/Release-iphoneos/SalaryTax.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SalaryTaxViewController.o"
>
> fatal error: error in backend: Constant Island pass failed to
>   converge! Command
>   /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   failed with exit code 1

Comment: If this is Xcode 4.5 then give Xcode 4.6 a try; there have been many improvements in the compiler...

Comment: You were right! XCode 4.6 worked at the first time.
Thank you